# Error presenting data in GSP by Grails' auto generated ID - get data type error

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm new to Grails, learning bit by bit, but I'm really struggling with this one.

Ok, so I'm trying to present data from a class in Grails. It stores data in a mySQL database. It all worked fine when we had a parameter in the class with an integer called "id", but we found out that Grails automagically assigns an 'id' row in the database table, so we removed that. Now, when I run this code in a gsp:

```
<g:each in="${Proposal.where {id == 1} }" var="proposal">
 <h3>
  ${proposal.name}
 </h3>
 <p>
  Starting date: <g:formatDate format="dd.MM.yyyy" date="${proposal.date_started}" />
 </p>
 <p>
  ending date:: <g:formatDate format="dd.MM.yyyy" date="${proposal.date_ended}" />
 </p>
 <p>
  description: ${ proposal.description }
 </p>   
</g:each>
```

The 'id == 1' part is just to get some dummy data out, I've made sure there's a line in the database with an id of 1. It will later be changed to take an input parameter, in order to show a dynamic details page.
when I try to navigate to this page, I get this error:

> URI
>       /site/proposal/
>       Class java.lang.ClassCastException
>       Message java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

The stack trace does not seem to do any more than show me where this occurs, points me to the location of the aforementioned code. The database table has a coloumn named 'id' which is a bigint. Shouldn't Grails be able to handle this kind of data type mismatch? An either way, isn't both long and bigint subsets of the Integer class?

Am I trying to list the data in a backwards manner? Is there a better tag to use? I'm confused and need a cup of tea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's good to separate the presentation (view) from your database query's, so a better place to this query is the controller or service if the query is more complex and have more variants.

```
class PropsalController {
  def showFirst() {
    def proposal = Proposal.get(1) //or Proposal.where{ id == 1L }
    [proposal: proposal]
  }
}
```

Since you filtered just one instance of your object, you don't need the each tag.

```
 <h3>
  ${proposal.name}
 </h3>
 <p>
  Starting date: <g:formatDate format="dd.MM.yyyy" date="${proposal.date_started}" />
 </p>
 <p>
  ending date:: <g:formatDate format="dd.MM.yyyy" date="${proposal.date_ended}" />
 </p>
 <p>
  description: ${ proposal.description }
 </p>
```

The cast exception that you're facing occurs because, by default, Grails will create a field id with the type `Long` and criterias aren't handling this cast. There's a [JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9447) created for this. If you need to use where queries, ensure to cast for Long your id.

Comment: Great, I'll try implementing this, thank you! It's a steep learing curve with Grails but it's fun!